# How to forbid moving around in the map on Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to forbid the option about moving around the map?

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center:{
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    },
    zoom: 15
});
```

I want my map to be positioned on the latitude and longitude, and the zoom to be specific, and the map to stay static (just like a picture), so you cannot see anything else than what is there in the map provided.

Answer (score 1):

try with static api:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-36.5443805,-62.0828073&zoom=7&size=800x600&maptype=road

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Disable dragging, zooming, the default UI, etc..

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
        lat: 42,
        lng: -72
    },
    zoom: 15,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bwxcfyzo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 42,
      lng: -72
    },
    zoom: 15,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```